# adding custom list to table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, koma-script, tocbasic

How can a list for a custom environment, created using KOMA script's `\DeclareNewTOC`, be included in the table of contents?  In the example below, the 'List of Photos' does not appear in the table of contents.

Also, is there an option that can be used to ensure that the format of a custom list (e.g., `\listofphotos`) matches that of the default lists (e.g., `\listoffigures`)?  (The `tocentrystyle` option seems relevant, but it is unclear how to relate this to the `listoffigures` style, and the entry styles listed in the KOMA-script manual [pp. 388--391] do not give the desired appearance.)

MWE:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tocbasic}
\usepackage{tocbibind}

\DeclareNewTOC[%
    type=photo,
    float,
    name=Photo,
    listname={List of Photos},
    counterwithin=chapter,
]{lop}

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \listoffigures
    \listofphotos

    \chapter{First}
    \begin{figure}[ht] \centering\fbox{Figure}\caption{A figure} \end{figure}
    \begin{photo}[ht]  \centering\fbox{Photo} \caption{A photo}  \end{photo}

    \chapter{Second}
    \begin{figure}[ht] \centering\fbox{Figure}\caption{A figure} \end{figure}
    \begin{photo}[ht]  \centering\fbox{Photo} \caption{A photo}  \end{photo}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use

```latex
\setuptoc{lop}{totoc}
```

or add option `setup=totoc` to the optional argument of `\DeclareNewTOC`.

Additional remark: `\DeclareNewTOC` uses by default `tocentryindent=1em` and `tocentrynumwidth=1.5em` while the figure entries in LoF have an indentation of `1.5em` and a number width of `2.3em`. So I would suggest to change the values of `tocentryindent` and `tocentrynumwidth` to the same as for figures.

Examples:

```latex
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tocbibind}% before tocbasic
\usepackage{tocbasic}

\DeclareTOCStyleEntries{tocline}{figure,table}% now controlled by tocbasic
\DeclareNewTOC[%
  type=photo,
  float,
  name=Photo,
  listname={List of Photos},
  counterwithin=chapter,
  setup=totoc,% entry in ToC
  tocentryindent:=figure,% same indentation as for figure
  tocentrynumwidth:=figure% same numwidth as for figure
]{lop}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listofphotos

\chapter{First}
\begin{figure}[ht] \centering\fbox{Figure}\caption{A figure} \end{figure}
\begin{photo}[ht]  \centering\fbox{Photo} \caption{A photo}  \end{photo}
\chapter{Second}
\begin{figure}[ht] \centering\fbox{Figure}\caption{A figure} \end{figure}
\begin{photo}[ht]  \centering\fbox{Photo} \caption{A photo}  \end{photo}
\end{document}
```

or

```latex
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tocbibind}% before tocbasic
\usepackage{tocbasic}

\DeclareNewTOC[%
  type=photo,
  float,
  name=Photo,
  listname={List of Photos},
  counterwithin=chapter,
  tocentryindent=1.5em,% same indentation as for figure
  tocentrynumwidth=2.3em% same numwidth as for figure
]{lop}
\setuptoc{lop}{totoc}% entry in ToC

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listofphotos

\chapter{First}
\begin{figure}[ht] \centering\fbox{Figure}\caption{A figure} \end{figure}
\begin{photo}[ht]  \centering\fbox{Photo} \caption{A photo}  \end{photo}
\chapter{Second}
\begin{figure}[ht] \centering\fbox{Figure}\caption{A figure} \end{figure}
\begin{photo}[ht]  \centering\fbox{Photo} \caption{A photo}  \end{photo}
\end{document}
```

The second suggestion works with older KOMA-Script versions too.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much.  The vertical spacing of entries also differs.  Do you know of any option governing this?  Following your example, I tried `tocentrybeforeskip:=figure` but the space between 'List of Photos' and the first entry is still larger than for 'List of Figures.'  I did not find an option for controlling vertical spacing in Table 15.1 of the KOMA-scripts manual (e.g., vspace, parskip, baselineskip).

Comment: Each `\chapter` adds vertical space to LoF and LoT. For the same space in  LoP you could use `\makeatletter
\AddToHook{cmd/@chapter/after}{\addtocontents{lop}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}}
\makeatother`.