# replicating the vertical spacing of \listoffigures in a custom list made with tocbasic

Tags: table-of-contents, tocbasic

I have used `tocbasic` to create a custom environment.  The appearance of this environment's listing, however, differs from the default listings (i.e., `\listoffigures` and `\listoftables`).

Differences in horizontal formatting (indentation, width) can be fixed using the `tocentryindent` and `tocentrynumwidth` [settings](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/623665).  However, differences in vertical spacing continue to be a problem (both between items and between the heading and the first item).

Does `\DeclareNewToc` accept options that allow replication of the vertical spacing of the default listings?  I failed to identify suitable options in the KOMA-script manual's Table 15.1 (TOC-entry style attributes).

MWE:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tocbasic}
\usepackage{tocbibind}

\DeclareTOCStyleEntries{tocline}{figure,table}
\DeclareNewTOC[%
    type=thing,
    float,
    name=Thing,
    listname={List of Things},
    counterwithin=chapter,
    tocentryindent:=figure,
    tocentrynumwidth:=figure
]{lop}



\begin{document}
    % no page breaks (tex.stackexchange.com/a/30750)
    \begingroup
        \let\cleardoublepage\relax
        \let\clearpage\relax
        \listoffigures
        \listoftables
        \listofthings
    \endgroup

    \chapter{First}
    \begin{figure}[ht] \centering\fbox{Figure}\caption{Figure 1} \end{figure}
    \begin{table}[ht]  \centering\fbox{Table} \caption{Table 1}  \end{table}
    \begin{thing}[ht]  \centering\fbox{Thing} \caption{Thing 1}  \end{thing}

    \chapter{Second}
    \begin{figure}[ht] \centering\fbox{Figure}\caption{Figure 2} \end{figure}
    \begin{table}[ht]  \centering\fbox{Table} \caption{Table 2}  \end{table}
    \begin{thing}[ht]  \centering\fbox{Thing} \caption{Thing 2}  \end{thing}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Edit: The following image, using the `xpatch` example from the answer, splices the three lists, which shows different vertical spacing between the heading and the first element.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If package `tocbasic` should controll the output of the list headings and the space after the heading, use

```latex
\renewcommand{\listoffigures}{\listoftoc[\listfigurename]{lof}}
\renewcommand{\listoftables}{\listoftoc[\listtablename]{lot}}
```

Each `\chapter` adds `10pt` vertical space to LoF and the LoT. To do the same for the new defined list, you have to patch `\@chapter`:

```latex
\makeatletter
\AddToHook{cmd/@chapter/after}{\addtocontents{lop}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}}
\makeatother
```

Example:

```latex
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tocbibind}% load before tocbasic
\usepackage{tocbasic}

\renewcommand{\listoffigures}{\listoftoc[\listfigurename]{lof}}
\renewcommand{\listoftables}{\listoftoc[\listtablename]{lot}}

\DeclareTOCStyleEntries{tocline}{figure,table}
\DeclareNewTOC[%
    type=thing,
    float,
    name=Thing,
    listname={List of Things},
    counterwithin=chapter,
    tocentryindent:=figure,
    tocentrynumwidth:=figure
]{lop}

\makeatletter
\AddToHook{cmd/@chapter/after}{\addtocontents{lop}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
% no page breaks (tex.stackexchange.com/a/30750)
\begingroup
    \let\cleardoublepage\relax
    \let\clearpage\relax
    \listoffigures
    \listoftables
    \listofthings
\endgroup

\chapter{First}
\begin{figure}[ht] \centering\fbox{Figure}\caption{Figure 1} \end{figure}
\begin{table}[ht]  \centering\fbox{Table} \caption{Table 1}  \end{table}
\begin{thing}[ht]  \centering\fbox{Thing} \caption{Thing 1}  \end{thing}

\chapter{Second}
\begin{figure}[ht] \centering\fbox{Figure}\caption{Figure 2} \end{figure}
\begin{table}[ht]  \centering\fbox{Table} \caption{Table 2}  \end{table}
\begin{thing}[ht]  \centering\fbox{Thing} \caption{Thing 2}  \end{thing}
\begin{figure}[ht] \centering\fbox{Figure}\caption{Figure 3} \end{figure}
\begin{table}[ht]  \centering\fbox{Table} \caption{Table 3}  \end{table}
\begin{thing}[ht]  \centering\fbox{Thing} \caption{Thing 3}  \end{thing}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or you could use

```latex
\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\xapptocmd{\@chapter}
  {\addtocontents{lop}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}}
  {}{\PatchFailed}
\makeatother
```

Example:

```latex
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tocbibind}% load before tocbasic
\usepackage{tocbasic}

\renewcommand{\listoffigures}{\listoftoc[\listfigurename]{lof}}
\renewcommand{\listoftables}{\listoftoc[\listtablename]{lot}}

\DeclareTOCStyleEntries{tocline}{figure,table}
\DeclareNewTOC[%
    type=thing,
    float,
    name=Thing,
    listname={List of Things},
    counterwithin=chapter,
    tocentryindent:=figure,
    tocentrynumwidth:=figure
]{lop}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\xapptocmd{\@chapter}
  {\addtocontents{lop}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}}
  {}{\PatchFailed}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
% no page breaks (tex.stackexchange.com/a/30750)
\begingroup
    \let\cleardoublepage\relax
    \let\clearpage\relax
    \listoffigures
    \listoftables
    \listofthings
\endgroup

\chapter{First}
\begin{figure}[ht] \centering\fbox{Figure}\caption{Figure 1} \end{figure}
\begin{table}[ht]  \centering\fbox{Table} \caption{Table 1}  \end{table}
\begin{thing}[ht]  \centering\fbox{Thing} \caption{Thing 1}  \end{thing}

\chapter{Second}
\begin{figure}[ht] \centering\fbox{Figure}\caption{Figure 2} \end{figure}
\begin{table}[ht]  \centering\fbox{Table} \caption{Table 2}  \end{table}
\begin{thing}[ht]  \centering\fbox{Thing} \caption{Thing 2}  \end{thing}
\begin{figure}[ht] \centering\fbox{Figure}\caption{Figure 3} \end{figure}
\begin{table}[ht]  \centering\fbox{Table} \caption{Table 3}  \end{table}
\begin{thing}[ht]  \centering\fbox{Thing} \caption{Thing 3}  \end{thing}
\end{document}
```

The result is the same as above.

---

It would be easier if you can switch to a KOMA-Script class (loads `tocbasic` automatically):

```latex
\documentclass[
  listof=totoc,
  index=totoc,
  bibliography=totoc,
  sfdefaults=false,% needs version 3.39 or newer
  listof=leveldown
]{scrreprt}

\setuptoc{toc}{totoc}% if there should really be an entry for ToC in ToC

\DeclareNewTOC[%
    type=thing,
    float,
    name=Thing,
    listname={List of Things},
    counterwithin=chapter,
    tocentryindent:=figure,
    tocentrynumwidth:=figure
]{lop}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\addchap{Lists}
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\listofthings

\chapter{First}
\begin{figure}[ht] \centering\fbox{Figure}\caption{Figure 1} \end{figure}
\begin{table}[ht]  \centering\fbox{Table} \caption{Table 1}  \end{table}
\begin{thing}[ht]  \centering\fbox{Thing} \caption{Thing 1}  \end{thing}

\chapter{Second}
\begin{figure}[ht] \centering\fbox{Figure}\caption{Figure 2} \end{figure}
\begin{table}[ht]  \centering\fbox{Table} \caption{Table 2}  \end{table}
\begin{thing}[ht]  \centering\fbox{Thing} \caption{Thing 2}  \end{thing}
\begin{figure}[ht] \centering\fbox{Figure}\caption{Figure 3} \end{figure}
\begin{table}[ht]  \centering\fbox{Table} \caption{Table 3}  \end{table}
\begin{thing}[ht]  \centering\fbox{Thing} \caption{Thing 3}  \end{thing}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Curiously I am unable to reproduce your output (I am using `pdflatex`).  The vertical spacing is still off for 'List of Things'.  Using pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.22 (TeX Live 2021).

Comment: You have to run twice.

Comment: Yes, even so (`pdflatex "$f.tex" && pdflatex "$f.tex"`).  The console output appears benign.

Comment: Did you use my MWE?

Comment: Yes, thank you. I can reproduce your output with the second MWE (the one with `scrreprt`).  Odd that the output using plain `report` is not reproducible.  Unfortunately, I don't think I can use `scrreprt` in my actual document because I must use a custom sty file, and I wind up getting various compilation errors (e.g., 'Class scrreprt Error: undefined old font command `\rm'.').

Comment: I am using an uptodate TeX Live and an uptodate MiKTeX. But I have added another suggestion using package `xpatch` for the patch.

Comment: Thank you very much.  That solved the spacing between the items, but the vertical space of the first element is still off for me.  I cannot tell if the same applies in your output.  I will post an image in my question to demonstrate.

Comment: You can add `\renewcommand{\listoffigures}{\listoftoc[\listfigurename]{lof}}` and the same for LoT. See my updated answer.

Comment: Brilliant, truly.  Thanks.