# retaining \listoffigures and \listoftables in \tableofcontents when they are controlled by tocbasic

Tags: table-of-contents, tocbibind, tocbasic

How can the List of Figures and List of Tables be included in the Table of Contents when they have been placed under the control of the `tocbasic` package?  Ordinarily, these listings can be included by using the package `tocbibind` without the options `notlof` and `notlot`.

[MWE:](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/623847)

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}% load before tocbasic
\usepackage{tocbasic}

% reset vertical spacing of LoF and LoT
\renewcommand{\listoffigures}{\listoftoc[\listfigurename]{lof}}
\renewcommand{\listoftables}{\listoftoc[\listtablename]{lot}}

% place LoF and LoT under control of tocbasic
\DeclareTOCStyleEntries{tocline}{figure,table}

% define custom listing
\DeclareNewTOC[%
    type=thing,
    float,
    name=Thing,
    listname={List of Things},
    counterwithin=chapter,
    setup=totoc,%                add this list to the Table of Contents
    tocentryindent:=figure,
    tocentrynumwidth:=figure
]{lop}

% match vertical spacing of LoF and LoT
\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\xapptocmd{\@chapter}
  {\addtocontents{lop}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}}
  {}{\PatchFailed}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \listoffigures
    \listoftables
    \listofthings

    \chapter{First}
    \begin{figure}[ht] \centering\fbox{Figure}\caption{Figure 1} \end{figure}
    \begin{table}[ht]  \centering\fbox{Table} \caption{Table 1}  \end{table}
    \begin{thing}[ht]  \centering\fbox{Thing} \caption{Thing 1}  \end{thing}

    \chapter{Second}
    \begin{figure}[ht] \centering\fbox{Figure}\caption{Figure 2} \end{figure}
    \begin{table}[ht]  \centering\fbox{Table} \caption{Table 2}  \end{table}
    \begin{thing}[ht]  \centering\fbox{Thing} \caption{Thing 2}  \end{thing}
    \begin{figure}[ht] \centering\fbox{Figure}\caption{Figure 3} \end{figure}
    \begin{table}[ht]  \centering\fbox{Table} \caption{Table 3}  \end{table}
    \begin{thing}[ht]  \centering\fbox{Thing} \caption{Thing 3}  \end{thing}
\end{document}
```

Contents page, lacking the LoF and LoT:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `\setuptoc{lof}{totoc}` and `\setuptoc{lot}{totoc}` in your preamble to add the two to your ToC:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}% load before tocbasic
\usepackage{tocbasic}


% reset vertical spacing of LoF and LoT
\renewcommand{\listoffigures}{\listoftoc[\listfigurename]{lof}}
\renewcommand{\listoftables}{\listoftoc[\listtablename]{lot}}

% place LoF and LoT under control of tocbasic
\DeclareTOCStyleEntries{tocline}{figure,table}

% define custom listing
\DeclareNewTOC[%
    type=thing,
    float,
    name=Thing,
    listname={List of Things},
    counterwithin=chapter,
    setup=totoc,%                add this list to the Table of Contents
    tocentryindent:=figure,
    tocentrynumwidth:=figure
]{lop}

\setuptoc{lof}{totoc}
\setuptoc{lot}{totoc}

% match vertical spacing of LoF and LoT
\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\xapptocmd{\@chapter}
  {\addtocontents{lop}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}}
  {}{\PatchFailed}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \listoffigures
    \listoftables
    \listofthings

    \chapter{First}
    \begin{figure}[ht] \centering\fbox{Figure}\caption{Figure 1} \end{figure}
    \begin{table}[ht]  \centering\fbox{Table} \caption{Table 1}  \end{table}
    \begin{thing}[ht]  \centering\fbox{Thing} \caption{Thing 1}  \end{thing}

    \chapter{Second}
    \begin{figure}[ht] \centering\fbox{Figure}\caption{Figure 2} \end{figure}
    \begin{table}[ht]  \centering\fbox{Table} \caption{Table 2}  \end{table}
    \begin{thing}[ht]  \centering\fbox{Thing} \caption{Thing 2}  \end{thing}
    \begin{figure}[ht] \centering\fbox{Figure}\caption{Figure 3} \end{figure}
    \begin{table}[ht]  \centering\fbox{Table} \caption{Table 3}  \end{table}
    \begin{thing}[ht]  \centering\fbox{Thing} \caption{Thing 3}  \end{thing}
\end{document}
```

[image]